# Can a fs function run quicker than one called before it?

Tags: node.js, express, fs

So I'm making a document-based database library and I'm concerned about something.
When lets say I get 2 requests almost at the same time that use the database, for example

```js
express.post("/storeSomeText/:text", (request, response) => {
  fs.appendFile("filePath", request.params.text, () => {
    response.send("success");
  });
})
```

so if I get 2 requests at almost the same time, is there ever a chance that the 2nd request handler's finishes before the one before it does?

if so, how do I avoid that from happening?

Comment: This could happen, and you need some kind of locking/synchronization. A slow but effective method would be to have a concept of transaction, and global locking per transaction.

Answer (score 0):

As @PiRocks suggest you can use locking / synchronization to solve this. Assuming "filePath" as key have some value against it say "locked" when an request starts processing and remove this key once you are done processing for this we can use **Redis** or some similar alternative.

Along with this you need to implement Retry Mechanism -- when an second request comes for the same filePath and you see there is an request already in-process for that filePath, you need to keep retrying till that request is processed.

You can use setTimeout to implement retry mechanism.

But best way will be to use some -- Queuing systems -- like RabbitMQ.